# Java HTTP Request Size

Tags: java, apache, size, httprequest

I created object of HTTPRequestBase from package org.apache.http.client.methods
after that I send the object vie  CloseableHttpClient

```
protected CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
HttpRequestBase httpRequest = this.createHttpRequest(request);
this.httpClient.execute(httpRequest, new BasicResponseHandler());
```

I want to check httpRequest size before I send it. I need it to be limited to a specific number of MB.

How can I check its size?

Comment: You can check the content-length header of the request to know the request size: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-determine-the-content-length-of-a-request.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not easy. The header and the body of the request are part of the HTTP application protocol.if your server use ssl,the certificate is sent as part of the SSL / TLS configuration ... before HTTP starts. Even the simple measurement of the amount of data in an HTTP request is tricky. A typical HTTP stack does not assemble the entire request message in one place and does not retain the cumulative total of the data sent. Depending on the HTTP stack you use, you can (in theory) use a custom socket factory and socket flows that count bytes sent.